# Create multiple tables sqlplus

Tags: database, sqlplus

I a trying to create a script that I will run in sqlplus (Oracle Database). It should create several tables, but when I execute it, it just says that it does not recognise any command that is written. This is my code right now:

```
create table STUDENT(

    Name                varchar2(40) not null,
    Student_Number      number(10),
    Class               number(10),
    Major               varchar2(40),

    primary key(Student_Number)

);


create table COURSE(

    Course_name     varchar2(40) unique,
    Course_number   varchar2(40),
    Credit_hours    number(10),
    Department      varchar2(40),

    primary key(Course_number)

);


create table SECTION(

    Section_Identifier      number(10),
    Course_number           number(10) not null,
    Semester                varchar2(40) not null,
    Year                    number(10) not null,
    Instructor              varchar2(40),


    primary key(Section_Identifier)
    foreign key(Course_number) references COURSE(Course_number)

);


create table GRADE_REPORT(

    Student_Number          number(10), 
    Section_Identifier      number(10),
    Grade                   varchar2(40),

    primary key(Student_Number, Section_Identifier)
    primary key(Student_Number) references STUDENT(Student_Number)
    foreign key(Section_Identifier) references SECTION(Section_Identifier)

);


create table PREREQUISITE(

    Course_number           varchar2(40),
    Prerequisite_number     varchar2(40),

    primary key(Course_number, Prerequisite_number)
    foreign key(Course_number) references COURSE(Course_number)
    foreign key(Prerequisite_number) references COURSE(Course_number)

);
```

I think this code should be fine, but I do not know if I am missing somethong essential.

Answer (score 1):

Well no, the code is not correct. You should probably debug your SQL

First off, you need to add a comma after every constraint declaration.

Secondly,

```
primary key(Student_Number) references STUDENT(Student_Number),
```

is incorrect syntax. You cannot declare a second primary key, and you cannot reference another table using the primary key constraint. That is a foreign key and needs to be written as a FK constraint.

In this situation you should probably not make your primary key a foreign key either. As each student can have multiple grade reports resulting in a 1:many relationship.

You should work on debugging your code using something like SQL Developer or Toad